# A question about matrix similarity and eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's suppose $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D_1$ so that there exists a $P_1 \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A = P_1 \cdot D_1 \cdot P_1^{-1}$. Furthermore, we can say that the $n$ column vectors of $P_1$ form a basis for the eigenspace of $A$.

Now suppose that $B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ , $B \neq A$, and suppose that $B$ is similar to the same diagonal matrix $D_1$ such that $A = P_2 \cdot D_1 \cdot P_2^{-1}$, $P_2 \in  GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Again we can say that the $n$ column vectors of $P_2$ form a basis for the eigenspace of $B$.

Now , since $A$ is similar to $D_1$ and $B$ is similar to $D_1$, and since similarity is an equivalence relation, (in particular transitivity holds), we can say that $A$ is similar to $B$.

My question is, since $A$ is similar to $B$, we know that there exists a conjugation matrix that takes us from $A$ to $B$, what can be said about this matrix's columns in regards to the eigenspaces of $A$ and $B$? Can anything be said?

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses your question to your satisfaction, but note the following. $A = P_1D_1P_1^{-1}$ can be rearranged to $D_1 = P_1^{-1}AP_1$. It follows that
$$
B = P_2D_1P_2^{-1} = P_2(P_1^{-1}AP_1)P_2^{-1} = (P_2P_1^{-1})A(P_2P_1^{-1})^{-1}.
$$
So, we can get the conjugation matrix from $P_1,P_2$, which in turn can be obtained from the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you, to an extent it does! Thank you!